# Django Template Language Not Rendering

Tags: python, django

I am brand new to Django and following along with the tutorial. I'm hoping this is just an obvious mistake, but I am unable to get my web browser to render anything written in the Django template language and I can't figure out why.

Here is my directory structure for some context: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXYrJ.jpg

**project/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('budget/', include('budget.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

**budget/urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:account_id>/', views.get_account, name='detail'),
]
```

**budget/views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from budget.models import Account, Transaction

def get_account(request, account_id):
    accts = Account.objects.filter(pk=account_id)

    context = {"test": accts}

    return render(request, 'budget/detail.html', context)
```

**budget/templates/budget/detail.html:**

```
<p>This is a {{ context.test }}</p>
```

When I visit `localhost:8000/budget/1` in my browser this is all that is rendered: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k2dL.jpg

Clearly Django is finding the template file and sending it to the browser, but anything that is written inside of {} does not get recognized or rendered at all.  I've followed along exactly with the tutorial and I have no idea why it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: It should be `<p>This is a {{ test }}</p>` in your template. The name `context` is undefined in your template. It is merely the variable name for the dictionary in your view.

Comment: Have you tried just `<p>This is a {{ test }}</p>`, without `context`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `context` in the expression in the template; all that you put in the context are "globals" in the template, so try

```
<p>This is a {{ test }}</p>
```

instead.

Django's template engine has the unfortunate property of being silent about nonexisting properties, so it's hard to debug stuff like this.

Comment: Thank you that did it! I did not realize that the variables provided by `context` were global - this had been throwing me off earlier when I was trying to write a more complicated template.